# Multiple calls to service method using criteria queries results in connection closed

Tags: grails, datasource

When using multiple data sources and calling a service method multiple times from the same controller method then criteria queries in the service method fail on second call and throws exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:312)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

It was also reported [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Connection-is-closed-question-td4641804.html) and someone opened a ticket in the old JIRA tracker but i cannot find it in github issue tracker now.

So can anyone help me find this issue in the new github tracker? or if anyone faced this issue then how did you solve this?

P.s @BDL the linked forum doesn't solve any issue and as you can read in the end, the person who asked the question created an issue and never updated the forum post

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where the error report has gone? If the question is "how can I call this multiple times?", then you should explain why the solutions in the linked forum didn't work for you.

Comment: @BDL i have updated the question